# Stange with htaccess on Laravel 5.4

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, routes

I have site on laravel 5.4 with API routes ( `prefix /API/v1/` ...). Now it's work fine. When I add some futures (Fo site routes, not API):

1. redirect from www to non www prefix
2. redirect from http to https
3. for API routes any types of request (with www or not, with http or https)

When I add redirects for this, it's work fine, but API have error (redirect to main site page).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$ [NC] # no for api 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# Redirect www to non-www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru$ [NC] 
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$ [NC] # no for api 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect http to https. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$ [NC] # no for api 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA] 

# Redirect Trailing Slashes... 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

# Handle Front Controller... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But when I test API routes it's redirect to main page example.ru/. For example:
I call POST to http://www.example.ru/api/v1/login, I return the main page html code.
 Where I do mistake. Please help. Best regards.

Comment: Can anybody to help?

Comment: Maybe has another way?